# Implementing "Pierre the Tight-rope" Walker from LYAH

Tags: haskell

[Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#error) presents an excellent introduction to `>>=` with an example.

Basically, `Pierre` is a tight-rope walker that has `Birds` (Int) on each side of his tight-rope (represented by a `tuple` (Int, Int)). Birds can land on each side (only one side at a time) with `addRight` and `addLeft`. If the difference of birds on left and right is > 4, then Pierre falls.

LYAH says to use the `Error` Monad:

> As an exercise, you can rewrite that with the error monad so that when the 
>   tightrope walker slips and falls, we remember how many birds were on each side 
>   of the pole when he fell.

Here's how I implemented it (but LYAH provided the type synonyms):

```
-- @author: LYAH
type Birds = Int
type Pole = (Birds, Birds)

addLeft :: Birds -> Pole -> Either Pole Pole
addLeft n (x, y) = let newLeft = x + n
                       newPole = (newLeft, y)
                       diff    = abs (newLeft - y)
                   in if (diff > 4) then Left  newPole
                      else               Right newPole

addRight :: Birds -> Pole -> Either Pole Pole
addRight n (x, y) = let newRight = y + n
                        newPole = (x, newRight)
                        diff    = abs (x - newRight)
                    in if (diff > 4) then Left  newPole
                       else               Right newPole                       

walkTightRope :: Either Pole Pole
walkTightRope = addLeft 2 (0,0) >>= addRight 4

walkTightRopeFailed :: Either Pole Pole
walkTightRopeFailed = addLeft 2 (0,0) >>= addRight 10 >>= addLeft 2

walkTightRopeDo :: Either Pole Pole
walkTightRopeDo = do 
    p1 <- addLeft 2 (0,0)   
    p2 <- addRight 1 p1
    return p2
```

Please critique my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see glaring flaws. A couple notes though:

-You could combine the addLeft/Right functions and pass in a tuple representing how many birds you want to add ( (0,2) for 2 right ); the functions are almost identical.

-I've found `where` bindings to read neater if I have more then 2 (personal choice).

-AFAIK, the Error Monad /= the Either Monad.